# Data Store has empty data property

Tags: extjs

I am working with Ext.js and trying to get a data Store set up and mapped to data fields on my FormPanel so that I can easily acess data input.
Something is missing in my mapping:
When I enter data in the textfields and hit my Submit button's submit handler, the data property on the store is blank.  I was expecting it to contain data input on the page.  Can someone help?  Thanks very much:

```
infoPanel = function () {
    this.store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad: true,
        root: 'Data',
        storeId: 'creditMemoStore',
        fields: ['shipto', 'billto', 'reasonCode', 'creditClaimed', 'adjustmentAmount', 'poNumber']
    });


this.fieldset = {
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    flex: 1,
    border: false,
    defaultType: 'field',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelWidth: 160,
            fieldLabel: 'Ship to',
            name: 'shipto',
            //dropdown
            allowBlank: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelWidth: 160,
            fieldLabel: 'Bill to',
            name: 'billto',
            //dropdown
            allowBlank: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelWidth: 160,
            fieldLabel: 'Reason Code',
            name: 'reasonCode',
            //dropdown
            allowBlank: false
        },
        {
            labelWidth: 160,
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            allowNegative: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Amount',
            allowBlank: false,
            name: 'creditClaimed'
        },
        {
            labelWidth: 160,
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            allowNegative: false,
            fieldLabel: 'Adjustment Amount',
            name: 'adjustmentAmount',
            allowBlank: false,
            maxLength: 5
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelWidth: 160,
            fieldLabel: 'Customer PO Number',
            allowBlank: false,
            name: 'poNumber',
            maxLength: 15
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelWidth: 160,
            fieldLabel: 'Debit Memo Number',
            allowBlank: false,
            name: 'dmNumber',
            maxLength: 50
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelWidth: 160,
            fieldLabel: 'Credit Memo Number',
            allowBlank: false,
            name: 'cmNumber',
            maxLength: 6
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            labelWidth: 160,
            fieldLabel: 'Currency Code',
            name: 'currencyCode',
            //dropdown
            allowBlank: false,
            maxLength: 3,
            value: 'USD'
        }
    ]
};

this.panel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 700,
    title: 'Create Credit Memo',
    height: 400,
    frame: true,
    id: 'creditMemoFormPanel',
    layout: 'vbox',
    layoutConfig: {
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [
        this.fieldset
    ],
    store: this.store,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Reset',
            handler: function () {
                this.up('form').getForm().reset();
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Submit',
            formBind: true,
            handler: function () {
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('creditMemoStore');
                var dataObject = { testPost: store.data};
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'CreateCreditMemo',
                        jsonData: Ext.JSON.encode(dataObject),
                        success: function() { Ext.Msg.alert('json post Success'); },
                        failure: function () { Ext.Msg.alert('json post Fail'); },
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

}

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var ip = new infoPanel();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ext.js Store is only used for records where more than set of data is displayed at a time.

The Store doesn't apply to a basic form.  The Ext.js Form posts the values of all of the fields automatically on submit.

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?42215-Getting-data-from-the-store-into-formpanel